# Why doesn't my activity UI update after leaving and returning? Code runs but no change on UI

Tags: android, user-interface, xamarin

I have an activity `MonitorActivity` which inherits `BaseActivity`. `BaseActivity` holds the `titlebar` along with an indicator image (red/green) to show connection status. `BaseActivity` holds the event handler to update the indicator when the connection status changes. It works fine if I enter `MonitorActivity`, connect/disconnect etc.

The issue is this:
If I go:

**`MonitorActivity`** -> **`OtherActivity`** -> **Return to `MonitorActivity`**

The code in the event handler runs, I can see the connection status images is being correctly set. The changes are no longer reflected in the UI though. `MonitorActivity` is a SingleTask and removing this fixes the issue for some reason, but this is not a solution for me. What is the issue here?

Relevent code:

```
private void BluetoothEventHandler(BluetoothStatusCodes btStatusCode)
    {
        RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
            switch (btStatusCode)
            {
                //case handling
            }
            _IvDeviceConnectionStatus.SetImageResource(_connectionStatus);
            _IvDeviceConnectionStatus.Invalidate();
        });
    }


protected override void OnResume()
    {

            RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                _IvDeviceConnectionStatus.SetImageResource(_connectionStatus);
            });
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the user guidelines on how to ask a good question before posting a question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thank You

Comment: I've tried to make it more descriptive and post some code, however it's more of an implementation issue so specific code isn't all that useful.

Comment: Could you made a basic demo that can reproduce this problem? And what launch modes does `OtherActivity` have:?